# Singleton design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to implement this singleton class in java . How can I
 put these variables in this class?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please try to implement a java class and if you have problems, come back.

Comment: @guenhter i cant do it , i am beginner

Comment: @sp00m I have made a singleton class but i dont know where to put these variables in this class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple example for your singleton. Feel free to add setters and getters as you need it for the fields. 
I'm not sure what the `set`-method in your diagram should do but maybe you don't need it anyway.

```
public class LibraryInfo {
    private static final LibraryInfo instance = new LibraryInfo();
    public static LibraryInfo getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    private LibraryInfo() {}

    private String name;
    private int phone;
    private String address;
    private String openTime;
    private String closeTime;

    // getters
}
```